# dpkg -get-selections command not working on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg

I am trying to use the gpkg -get-selections command on Ubuntu.  I am kind of new to Ubuntu and really just following a tutorial on how to properly install Tomcat :)\

The tutorial is here:
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/installing-tomcat-6-on-ubuntu/

The example is there, but locally I get this error:

```
dpkg: unknown option -g

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use `dselect' or `aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;
Type dpkg --license for copyright license and lack of warranty (GNU GPL) [*].
```

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is `dpkg --get-selections`, not <strike>dpkg -get-selections</strike>.